# References in Cython

Tags: python, c++, reference, cython

I'm having some trouble experimenting with references in Cython.
I'm using this code to create an int and make a reference to it.

```
cdef int i = 10;
cdef int& integer_ref = i;
```

However, I cant figure out how to change the value of i through integer_ref. In C, I'd just use `integer_ref = some_other_value`, and that would set the value of `i` to `some_other_value`.

However, doing that in cython returns an error because assignment to a reference isn't allowed. 
I tried `integer_ref[0] = some_other_value` as well, but that attempts to index an `int &` which is not allowed. What should i be using?
I found [this post on the cython-users list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cython-users/j58Sp3QMrD4) that seems to imply that it's a known bug, but I'm not too sure. The workaround in the link of using `(&integer_ref)[0] = some_other_value` also did not work for me.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that the workaround proposed in the link is not `integer_ref[0] = other_value`, it's `(&integer_ref)[0] = other_value`.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't mean to imply that i used `integer_ref[0] = other_value` as a workaround from the link. The workaround from the link also didn't work for me, throwing a long compile error. Thanks for catching that, I forgot to mention.

Answer (score 0):

You could use standard pointers to tackle this problem. For example,

```
def test():
    cdef:
        int i = 10
        int* ref = &i

    print(ref[0])  # Prints 10
    ref[0] = 5
    print(i)  # Prints 5
```